# Which book is the best for introduction to analysis social network using python3

Tags: data-mining, python, social-network-analysis

I am a beginner studying **social network analysis**.
I installed python 3 just 2 weeks ago.
There are a lot of books for python and social network analysis.

I couldn't choose one of them.
I found one book named "Mining the Social Web (Analyzing Data from Facebook, Twitter, Linkedln, and Other Social Media Sites)" written by Matthhew A. Russell.
This book looks very interesting and fits in my purpose, but it is based on python 2.

Is there any good books with **python 3**? I usually use **Twitter, Facebook, or Blog data**.

In addition, could you recommend any good book for **nodeXL and UCINET?**

Comment: Requests for book recommendations and the like are generally off topic on StackExchange

Comment: @SeanOwen: Actually, I'm not sure that book recommendations should be considered off-topic here. My logic and experience of Cross Validated, which is a serious forum, suggests that book recommendations are OK, as long as the requests are related to the topic of discussion. Please let me know, if there exist a corresponding DS Meta discussion, so that I could share my opinion.

Comment: @SeanOwen Oh. I didn't know that. This was my first question on StackExchange. I will try to be more careful next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Russell's book is fine. You might also like [Social Network Analysis for Startups](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020424.do). All the examples are in python. You can do all your analysis in that using packages like `networkx`. NodeXL is for the Excel crowd. Definitely not the ideal tool for the job; I would shy away from it.

The obvious book for NodeXL is [Analyzing Social Media Networks with NodeXL](http://www.elsevier.com/books/analyzing-social-media-networks-with-nodexl/hansen/978-0-12-382229-1), which is written by the authors of NodeXL.